# Less verbose access logs using expressjs/morgan

Tags: apache, logging, access-log, morgan

I am using https://github.com/expressjs/morgan to log HTTP requests and get log output like

```
169.228.10.248 - - [27/Jan/2019:11:10:39 +0000] "POST /api/Users/ HTTP/1.1" 400 92 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
169.228.10.248 - - [27/Jan/2019:11:10:40 +0000] "GET /rest/user/whoami HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
169.228.10.248 - - [27/Jan/2019:11:10:40 +0000] "POST /rest/user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 730 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
169.228.10.248 - - [27/Jan/2019:11:10:40 +0000] "GET /rest/continue-code HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
169.228.10.248 - - [27/Jan/2019:11:10:40 +0000] "GET /rest/user/whoami HTTP/1.1" 200 112 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
169.228.10.248 - - [27/Jan/2019:11:10:40 +0000] "GET /api/Challenges/?name=Score%20Board HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

(see https://pastebin.com/4U1V1UjU for more)

Can I somehow reduce the verbosity of these logs? I am totally not interested in the browser information for example. Thanks in advance for your help!